# Select2: Tags: Different Text for selected Tags

Tags: jquery-select2

How can I have a different Text when a Element is selected then what is displayed yet.

[image]

Background: The Text I display for in the Option is pretty long, so I want to show a shorter version, when it is slected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [templateSelection](https://select2.github.io/options.html#templateSelection) option of Select2 with some custom attribute to option tag

HTML:

```
<select id="long" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
        <option data-custom="" value="all">All </option>
        <option data-custom="Lorem ipsum" value="#FF0000">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</option>
        <option data-custom="Sed do" value="#00FF00">Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</option>
        <option data-custom="Ut enim" value="#0000FF">Ut enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation</option>
        <option data-custom="Duis aute" value="#FFFF00">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse</option>
    </select>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(function() {
            jQuery('#long').select2({
                templateSelection: function (selection) {
                    return jQuery(selection.element).data('custom');
                }
            });
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rijokpaul/phz9e5cs/4/